# Drupal 8 support active language translation?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8 for my project. Although it supports multiple languages, content editing is done in English, What if I change the language to french and then edit some content in English, will it automatically convert the edited content in french?

Answer (score 0):

When you open node editing page like this:

```
en/node/251/edit
```

This means that you are editing English version of node with id 251. And if you open:

```
de/node/251/edit
```

you will be editing German version of the same node. So that language prefix is deterring what language version are you editing.

Drupal interface is also respecting that language prefix so if you are editing German version of content interface will also be on German.

So if node is multilingual (it's enabled in content type settings) and you change that "en" to "de" you will be editing the German translation for the same node and Drupal's interface will also switch from English to German.